# Internal error when trying to change avatar

Tags: bug, profile-picture

I tried to change account logo (picture).

But nothing happened.

In my Chrome inspector I got an error :

```
GET http://meta.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/popup/change-picture/245932 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Before posting this question, I check this related question :

[Is the change picture button broken?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121878/is-the-change-picture-button-broken)

I tried with Chrome, Epiphany, Chromium, and Firefox (Ubuntu OS)

So, is this functionality broken ?

Comment: Same here in Chrome (Win8.1), happens on all sites that I checked, except site-metas (weird)

Comment: Ouf ! Thank you I thought that I was the only one ^^

Comment: It seems to work again?

Comment: Seems to be working here. Are you able to change your avatar now or is it still busted for you?

Comment: Yes it works now ^^ !